# Print list of tuple F#

Tags: f#

I have some code I am trying to test, that is supposed to merge two int lists of same length into a tuple list. I have got it to compile but I cannot find out if it works as I am having trouble printing the result.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    let myList = [5;15;20;25;30;200]
    let myList2 = [6;16;21;26;31;201]

    let rec tupleMaker (list1: int list) (list2: int list) =
        match list1, list2 with
        | (h1 :: tail1),(h2 :: tail2)->
          let (a,b) = (h1,h2)
          (a,b) :: tupleMaker tail1 tail2
        | _,_->
          []

    let z = tupleMaker myList, myList2
    //printfn z
    //printfn %A
```

The printfn does not work and neither has anything else I tried, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `printfn` takes two parameters, you have only supplied one in both cases in your solution. Try giving it both the string to format and the data for said format. `printfn "%A" z`. Also your function application in `z` definition looks wrong, I think you want to get rid of the comma between `myList` and `myList2`

Comment: Oops, thanks a ton, seems to be working now!

Answer (score 5):

Note: The OP has not been seen in months so this answer will probably never get an accept vote. Don't let that stop you from thinking it is not a correct answer.

First to generate a list of tuples.
This uses two different types of list to make the answer more useful in general.

```
let myList: int list = [1;2;3]
let myList2 : string list = ["a";"b";"c"]

let listOfTuple:(int * string) list = List.zip myList myList2
```

There are many ways to print a list of tuples, but the basic idea is to use `List.iter` to access the individual tuples in the list and then apply standard means to access the items in the tuple.

Example 1:

This doesn't use `List.iter`. It uses just `printfn %A`. This is useful when you are stuck trying to figure out why something will not print and just need to see the data as the system sees it.

```
 printfn "%A" listOfTuple
```

Result:

```
[(1, "a"); (2, "b"); (3, "c")]
```

Example 2:

This uses `List.iter` with `printfn %A`. This is useful when you know the data is a list but don't know the type of the individual items.

```
listOfTuple |> 
    List.iter (printfn "%A")
```

Result:

```
(1, "a")
(2, "b")
(3, "c")
```

Example 3:

This uses `List.iter` with a tuple deconstructor, e.g. `let (a,b) = values`, to get at the individual values of the tuple. This is useful if you want to print every value of every item in the list.

```
listOfTuple |> 
    List.iter(
        fun values -> 
            let (a,b) = values
            printfn ("%i, %s") a b
    )
```

Result:

```
1, a
2, b
3, c
```

Example 4:

This uses `List.iter` with a `match` statement to get at the individual values of the tuple. This is useful if you want to do more complicated processing, such as filtering before printing, or having different printing messages and/or formats for different values.

```
listOfTuple |>
    List.iter( 
        fun values ->
            match values with
            | (a,_) when a > 1 -> 
                printfn ("%i") a
            | (_,_) -> ()
    )
```

Result

```
2
3
```

Answer (score 4):

You just implemented `List.zip`:

```
List.zip myList myList2    
//val it : (int * int) list =
//  [(5, 6); (15, 16); (20, 21); (25, 26); (30, 31); (200, 201)]
```